# How to export dynamic variable in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm currently converting some code from Node JavaScript into TypeScript

I have a file called keys.js

```
let keys;
try {
  // eslint-disable-next-line security/detect-non-literal-fs-filename
  keys = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(credsPath, 'utf8'));
} catch (error) {
  return logger.error('initKeysParseError', error, { credsPath });
}

if (keys) {
  logger.info('initKeysSuccess', 'keys ready', null);

  return (module.exports.keys = keys);
}

return logger.error('initKeysError', null, { credsPath });
```

And when I wanted to use `keys` in another file, I would

```
const { keys } = require('./keys');
console.log(keys.account.username);
```

I'm having some issue doing this in typescript

How can I initialize the keys variable only once and then be able to do
`import keys from './keys';`

?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tried this but I think:

```
let keys;
try {
  // eslint-disable-next-line security/detect-non-literal-fs-filename
  keys = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(credsPath, 'utf8'));
  if (keys) {
    logger.info('initKeysSuccess', 'keys ready', null);
  } else {
    logger.error('initKeysError', null, { credsPath });
  }
} catch (error) {
  logger.error('initKeysParseError', error, { credsPath });
}

export { keys };
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should wrap your code in keys.js in some function

```
exports.getKeys = function() {
  let keys;

  try {
    // eslint-disable-next-line security/detect-non-literal-fs-filename
    keys = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(credsPath, 'utf8'));
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error('initKeysParseError', error, { credsPath });
  }

  if (keys) {
    logger.info('initKeysSuccess', 'keys ready', null);
    return keys;
  }

  logger.error('initKeysError', null, { credsPath })
  return keys;
}
```

```
const module = require('./keys.js')
const keys = module.getKeys();
```

and maybe you should switch to use esnext module with `import ... from ...` syntax, you can do that by changing tsconfig.json  compilerOptions to `"module": "esnext"`

Comment: I like it!
But is there a way to not also have to do the `.getKeys()` part?